# Xcode v11.1 and 11.2 - Build OK but Archive fails - GRPC

Tags: ios, xcode, google-api, grpc

I'm trying to run some of these samples: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples
but I'm getting some errors when archiving the iOS project, due to some GoogleApis libraries:

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'GRPCClient': '/MyProject/iphoneos/gRPC/GRPCClient.framework/Headers/internal_testing/GRPCCall+InternalTests.h'
```

`google-umbrella.h` fails because it doesn't find the GoogleApis framework headers

Running the project on a device in debug mode works, this error happens only when archiving. I guess this problems are due to something related with headers in Xcode.

Can anyone throw some light?

Comment: Which version of gRPC are you using?

Comment: The example in /ios-docs-samples/speech/Objective-C/Speech-gRPC-Nonstreaming actually archived well for me. I suggest you get a newer version of gRPC since in the newest version (1.25.0) the file GRPCCall+InternalTests.h does not seem to be in the pod by default.